# How to pass Id value to window.location.href in MVC application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am working on MVC application in that I need to render page to another action in MVC application for that I need to pass Id parameter to that Action.

Here is my Code.

```
var CardCode=$('#CardCode').val();
if (str.substr("successfully")) {
    window.location.href='@Url.Action("EditPartner","MstPartner",new { id = CardCode})';
}
```

in that code when I am passing value to that id, i.e `id=CardCode` that is not allowed there then how to pass CardCode value to that action?
Please give some suggestion.

Comment: You need to understand *which* code renders *when*: The Razor code gets evaluated on the server and therefore can't be mixed with JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you can't pass a variable in there. It only works if value is hardcoded

```
window.location.href='@Url.Action("EditPartner","MstPartner",new { id = "123"})';
```

What you can do is use a `Replace` method

```
var CardCode=$('#CardCode').val();
if (str.substr("successfully")) {
    window.location.href='@Url.Action("EditPartner","MstPartner",new { id = "CC"})'.replace("CC",CardCode);
}
```

Comment: yes it is working.Thank you very much for your quick suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do it dynamic on client side that you should do it by means of javascript

```
function replaceUrlParam(url, paramName, paramValue){
    if(paramValue == null)
        paramValue = '';
    var pattern = new RegExp('\\b('+paramName+'=).*?(&|$)')
    if(url.search(pattern)>=0){
        return url.replace(pattern,'$1' + paramValue + '$2');
    }
    return url + (url.indexOf('?')>0 ? '&' : '?') + paramName + '=' + paramValue 
}

var url = '@Url.Action("EditPartner","MstPartner",new { id = CardCode})';
var newUrl = replaceUrlParam(url,"Id","OtherCardCode");
```